# Strange Mystery Border around an Image.Network

Tags: image, flutter, url

When I display any image using Image.Network - I get a very strange grey left and right border.

The image is loading in PNG, but I have tried JPG - and also resized the image, but no matter what size or format, I'm left with a grey left and right border each time - and have no idea where it's coming from?? - can anyone please help?

[image]

The code to display the image is as follows:

```
Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0, top: 10.0),
                          child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      RaisedButton(
                                        onPressed: _launchURL,
                                        child: Image.network(
                                          'http://myurl.com/myimage.png',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                              ])),
```

Can anyone see what could possibly be creating this box - just also to add momentarily before the image loads, the grey box is visible - shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Is it the RaisedButton placement 'area'?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got to the answer with my very last question.

It's the background properties of the Raised Button. By adding the following to RaisedButton, it changes the grey to match the white background:

```
color: Colors.white,
```

So it becomes:

```
RaisedButton(
                                        onPressed: _launchURL,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        child: Image.network(
                                          'http://myurl.com/myimage.png',
                                        ),
                                      ),
```